# Using a Computed Value that accesses a function in the parent viewmodel in Knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to use a function that is defined in my main view model from inside a sub view model.  I have created a fiddle that I think should demonstrate what I am trying to do and doesn't work correctly [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pltaylor3/gqfBf/3/).  Also is there a better way to accomplish what I am doing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you wanted to be able to lookup the manufacturer list in the parent viewmodel from the child Part model. I changed a few things in your fiddle and created a new one that resolves this: 
http://jsfiddle.net/johnpapa/dsZ76/

First, the `data-bind` attributes were using value when they should have been using text. The `<p>` tags should also use a closing p tag. Also, you were binding to the manufacturer property, but that is the object being returned so it should have been `manufacturer().name`.

In the JavaScript, I added  "this" as the second parameter to the computed. "this" then becomes the owner so you can use it inside the computed function to represent the Part model.  Then I changed your function that does the lookup to do an equality check instead of using `stringStartsWith`. The definition for the `getManaufacturers` was moved before the call create the Parts (because the Parts models call it). Finally, I pass in "self" to the Part function, which turns into the parent parameter.

This should do it.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Sorry for the sloppy errors in the fiddle like the <p> tag.

Comment: no worries. the span tag is like that too. the behavior you will see in Knockout when you forget to use a closing tag is that "usually" the first binding will work, but none thereafter. just a tip :)

Comment: I'll take all the tips I can get!!

Answer (score 1):

John is faster than me :) I made the similar changes. http://jsfiddle.net/gurkavcu/qKFHB/

Comment: I noticed you decided to force the values in the lookup function to be strings. clever :-)

Comment: Why is forcing the values to be strings desirable?

Comment: The function he as using required strings, so it just put them on the same playing field. Its just a judgment call there.